# Yii CListView ajax post data

Tags: yii

When using Yii CListView with Ajax, when I click next or previous button using Yii default Pager, I want to post additional parameters to controller - For example, I want to post search keyword, userid...etc to update criteria in the controller - BUT I DON'T KNOW HOW TO DO THAT.

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advanced,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should to extend CListView component.

```
public function registerClientScript()
{
    /*deleted*/
    $options=array(
        'ajaxUpdate'=>$ajaxUpdate,
        'ajaxVar'=>$this->ajaxVar,
        'pagerClass'=>$this->pagerCssClass,
        'loadingClass'=>$this->loadingCssClass,
        'sorterClass'=>$this->sorterCssClass,
    );

    /*deleted*/
    $cs->registerScript(__CLASS__.'#'.$id,"jQuery('#$id').yiiListView($options);");
}
```

May be you should append your own params to the options array.